# Insert into Hive table from select statement with different schema

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql, etl

I have a target external table with following columns:

```
UPDATED_BY STRING,
Name STRING
```

I want to insert data into target table from a source table with following columns:

```
UPDATED_BY STRING,
abc STRING
```

both tables are partitioned by year, day and month. Is it possible to insert data of col `abc` from source table into target table's `Name` column? Please help

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work.

Just alias the source table column with the destination column name.

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE target_external_table PARTITION(YEAR,MONTH,DAY) --check partition order in your table. I believe this is the order.
SELECT
    UPDATED_BY,
    abc AS name,
    YEAR,
    MONTH,
    DAY
FROM source_table;
```

Comment: can i add a where clause at the end like `FROM source_table where year=2010` ? i do not have `year`, `month` and `day` as columns in source table do i need to specify them? both source and target are already partitioned over year, month and day

Comment: I don’t understand this: "i do not have year, month and day as columns in source table" as you are saying "both source and target are already partitioned over year, month and day".

Comment: And yes, you can add WHERE, HAVING, ORDER BY. As long as your column name matches with the target table. If doesn’t ALIAS them with target column name

Comment: Partition is nothing nothing but a special type of column. You can treat them as column. You will not have any problem there